# twig kint permissions buggy

Tags: theming, users

When debugging with kint in a twig tpl the output is seen also by site visitors although they are not logged in.

Permissions "Access kint information" are set just for admin.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I wonder why this is getting downrated?! No legit question?
I am not the first person who discovered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is probably related to caching, you can argue that it's a bug in devel/kint module and that is should have an implementation to handle this.

I would argue that the use of kint in a template file is made for running the site in development mode and if you disable caches (which is a really idea on an actual production site) it should work just fine.

Comment: hi there. Caches are disabled.